# How to source images from my storage to NetSuite without uploading them to the file cabinet?

Tags: image, storage, netsuite

In order to place images in the web store, they have to be uploaded to the file cabinet and then the file name needs to be associated with the item.

What I am looking to do, is to source the images from my current internal storage to NetSuite and still be able to view the images on the website. I am trying to find a way to do this because I don't want to have to upload them all individually or with a mass upload.

Comment: Where is your website hosted, on NetSuite's Suitecommerce Platform or some e-Commerce Platform like Magento?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom item field of type "text" and associate the field to the item record.

You can then place the full path to your image in the field you just created and reference the custom field in your templates.

This will allow you to use urls from your own host, but dynamically be able to use them within the NetSuite web store.